# How do I change the color palette in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, themes, angular-material, angular-cli

In my angular4 project, built with angular-cli, I have the following scss custom theme which works fine:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$mf-app_primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$mf-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$mf-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$mf-app-theme: mat-light-theme($mf-app_primary, $mf-app-accent, $mf-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($mf-app-theme);
```

It is directly copied from a tutorial.

I do not understand how to change the colors within this file. I want to import my own palette. Do I have to change a palette file within Material? What is the format/syntax I need? Where is palette.scss within the cli build?

Comment: Change $mat-indigo for $mat-blue for example ;) refer to the palette form Material Colors